Receiving TaskCanceledException when using passwordless authentication with Azure Functions and Entity Framework with SQL Server
I am using Isolated Azure Functions and SQL Server with Entity Framework. This is configuration I am having inside my Program.cs of corresponding Azure Function App:
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureSQL");

services.AddDbContext<ReportDataDbContext>(options =>
{
    options
        .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging(queryParamsLogging);
});

My Azure Function has UserManagedIdentity assigned and my SQL Server has assigned to this UserManagedIdentity too.
From my pipeline in Azure DevOps I am trying to apply migration via http request to Azure Function.
  displayName: 'Applying Migrations EF'
  inputs:
    pwsh: true
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $env = "${{ parameters.env }}"
      # step 1 receive auth token to call az function
      $applyMigrationFunctionUrl = "https://api-$env.azazello.pl/${{ parameters.apiTypeUrl }}/migrations/apply/${{ parameters.apiTypeUrl }}"
      
      echo "Receiving application token..."
      $body = @{
          client_id = "${{ parameters.clientId }}"
          scope = "${{ parameters.authAllowedAudience }}/.default"
          client_secret = "${{ parameters.secretId}}"
          grant_type = "client_credentials"
      }
      
      $tenantId = "${{ variables.tenantId }}"
      $azToken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token" -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $body | Select-Object -ExpandProperty access_token

      echo "Token received."
      $headers = @{
          'Authorization' = "Bearer $azToken"
      }
      # step 2 call apply migrations endpoint of corresponding az-function
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -ConnectionTimeoutSeconds 180 -OperationTimeoutSeconds 180 -RetryIntervalSec 20 -MaximumRetryCount 3  -Uri $applyMigrationFunctionUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers

Endpoint code:

   [Function(nameof(ApplyMigrationsAllReporting))]
   public async Task<IActionResult> ApplyMigrationsAllReporting(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "migrations/apply/api/reporting")]
   HttpRequest httpRequest,
   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      _logger.LogWarning(
      "[ApplyMigrationsAllReporting] Applying all pending migrations. CancellationToken: {CancellationToken}", cancellationToken);
      await _dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync(cancellationToken);
      return new OkResult();
   }

The problem is: sporadically after deployment the first request can be failed with the following error:
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection+<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection+<OpenInternalAsync>d__70.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection+<OpenAsync>d__66.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator+<>c__DisplayClass20_0+<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator+<>c__DisplayClass20_0+<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteAsync>d__7`2.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository+<ExistsAsync>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator+<MigrateAsync>d__15.MoveNext (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=8.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Test.Azure.ReportApi.Http.DbMigrationFunctions+<ApplyMigrationsAllReporting>d__3.MoveNext (Test.Azure.ReportApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ReportApi\Test.Azure.ReportApi\Http\DbMigrationsFunctions.cs:32)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Test.Azure.ReportApi.DirectFunctionExecutor+<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext (Test.Azure.ReportApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\ReportApi\Test.Azure.ReportApi\obj\Release\net8.0\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.Generators.FunctionExecutorGenerator\GeneratedFunctionExecutor.g.cs:50)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.OutputBindings.OutputBindingsMiddleware+<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core, Version=1.18.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=551316b6919f366c: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\OutputBindings\OutputBindingsMiddleware.cs:13)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore.FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=551316b6919f366c: D:\a\_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore\src\FunctionsMiddleware\FunctionsHttpProxyingMiddleware.cs:48)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionsApplication+<InvokeFunctionAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Core, Version=1.18.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=551316b6919f366c: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\DotNetWorker.Core\FunctionsApplication.cs:89)

My connection string is:
Server=tcp:sqlMy,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Default;Encrypt=True;User Id=GUID_OF_UserManagedIdentity;Database=MyDb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=60;TrustServerCertificate=True
I added retry in powershell invoke-restmethod (code above in powershell), and with retry everything works fine in sum -> first request may fail sporadically, but with retry the second request(next try with fully the same data) executes successfully. So, the connection is fine with db. UserManagedIdentity and corresponding user in database has all required roles(db_reader,db_writer,ddl_admin).
Goal: I would like to avoid this retry in powershell and understand why this task is cancelled when I try to migrate database even if there are no pending migration, just sporadically fail after deployment...
It started to be occurred when I tried using passwordless authentication, before that, I was using sql authnetication and everything was fine
I have found similar topic but without answer :( :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/answers/questions/1454998/running-database-update-for-entityframeworkcore-re
I appreciate any help and advices!

Probably because migration takes some time and HTTP request has 30 seconds time-out by default.

Hi there, May I know if the issue is reproducible if you run the script via local PowerShell not in the PowerShell pipeline task? This may help isolate the cause of the issue. Thx.

@AlvinZhao-MSFT no it is not redproduceable

What if adding some time for waiting like Start-Sleep -s 30 as suggested by @SvyatoslavDanyliv?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I tried even 10 minutes :) no helps(

You PowerShell script simply generates token as the API request header and then calls the function API right? Is there any error in the pipeline logs?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT yes, exactly. error in pipeline before retry was just : "invoke-restmethod failed", after retry no errors in pipeline. But in logs of azure "task was cancelled always was and is"

It was so weird that a simple API call could fail and only failed when the request was sent from an agent environment. I was really not sure if the issue was related to what machine the request was sent from. If that API call was simply to trigger the function, did you observer the function was triggered or was never triggered at all? In my opinion, the error indicated the function was triggered and after that the workflow in that function somehow failed to connection to the SQL db. If that was the case, what were the states of the function and SQL resources when the issue occurred?

I was also facing a similar issue with TaskCanceledException in my project. The second option below helped me to resolve my case. Referring to this issue, you can try several things to fix your issue:

Try to remove all packages referenced to Microsoft.Extensions.* if you do not use ASP.NET Core integration in your isolated functions.

If you use ASP.NET Core integration, try adding <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun> and <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> or <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier> to the *.csproj file of your Azure function project.



yes, the 2 point helped me, thanks but it was really strange....................
